# How to find number of messages in IBM MQ in Mule

Tags: mule4

Is there a way to find the count of messages in IBM MQ in Mule.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The Mule IBM MQ Connector has operations to read and publish messages, but none for performing queue management functions or queries.

It is because the connector implementation uses the Java JMS API application which has that limitation.

Note that usually client's of message brokers consume messages but don't attempt to query or control que queues.

You can find IBM MQ admin commands to query the information.